# How do I build a kernel using patches from LKML?

Tags: fedora, linux-kernel, patch

I would like to compile a kernel for fedora which contains some not yet merged patches which fix a hardware device of mine. The patches are located [here](https://lkml.org/lkml/2019/10/16/1091).

I have read [the guide on compiling a kernel for Fedora](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Building_a_custom_kernel).

What I am unsure of is how I get the patches from the mailing list and then apply them to my copy of the Linux source code. Obviously I could copy and paste the changes by hand in to the code but I assume there is a much better way than that. From what I understand you can create a git patch file which you can then apply. What would be the best way to apply this code contained in the emails?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This patch series was sent to `linux-input`, so it’s available on [Patchwork](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-input/list). To find it, you’ll need to remove the “Action Required” filter at the top of the screen; you’ll then find v2 of the patch (which matches your link), and also [v3 of the patch](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/11197515/) which is the version that was merged. There’s a handy “Series” link in the top-right-hand corner: click on that, save the resulting file, then in your kernel tree,

```
git am /path/to/Logitech-G920-fixes.patch
```

will apply it for you.

On the current kernel tree, you will need to apply [this patch](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/11173117/) first; so download that, and apply

```
git am /path/to/HID-Fix-assumption-that-devices-have-inputs.patch
git am /path/to/Logitech-G920-fixes.patch
```

To figure that out, I added [the HID](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/hid/hid.git) tree as a remote, then looked at the log for `drivers/hid/hid-logitech-hidpp.c`:

```
git remote add hid https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/hid/hid.git
git fetch hid
git log HEAD..hid/for-next drivers/hid/hid-logitech-hidpp.c
```

If you’re going to work with Patchwork again in the future, it’s worth downloading [`pwclient`](https://patchwork.kernel.org/pwclient/) and configuring `~/.pwclientrc`:

```
[options]
default = linux-input

[linux-input]
url = https://patchwork.kernel.org/xmlrpc/
```

Then you can run `pwclient git-am 11173117` and `pwclient git-am 11197515` to apply the patch series directly.

Comment: When I run this I get ```Applying: HID: logitech-hidpp: split g920_get_config()
error: patch failed: drivers/hid/hid-logitech-hidpp.c:2081
error: drivers/hid/hid-logitech-hidpp.c: patch does not apply
Patch failed at 0001 HID: logitech-hidpp: split g920_get_config()```

Comment: What git hash are you applying the patch on? Put another way, how did you get the kernel tree you’re using?

Comment: I just ran 

git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git

Comment: Ah, you need another patch on Linus’ tree, see my updated answer for details.

Answer (score 5):

There's a dedicated program for patching - `patch`. It's widely available across various OSs. Search for it in you repository, it should be there. Then consult your `man patch`.

- A preview: https://linux.die.net/man/1/patch
- [Patch on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_%28Unix%29)

Comment: patch is designed to ignore parts of the file it's given that don't look like a patch; the idea being one can pipe the entire email/post straight to patch and things will _just work_.

Comment: If your linux source tree is a git clone, then `git am` is better because it will actually register the patch in git. Moreover, it'll let you resolve conflicts in a similar way `git merge` does, unlike `patch`, which will just put rejected hunks into a `*.rej` file.